# Fast calculation of RMS gives NaNs in Java - floating point error?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, floating-point, nan

I'm getting a perplexing result doing math with floats.  I have code that should never produce a negative number producing  a negative number, which causes NaNs when I try to take the square root.

This code appears to work very well in tests.  However, when operating on real-world (i.e. potentially very small, seven and eight negative exponents) numbers, eventually sum becomes negative, leading to the NaNs.  In theory, the subtraction step only ever removes a number that has already been added to the `sum`; is this a floating-point error problem?  Is there any way to fix it?

The code:

```
public static float[] getRmsFast(float[] data, int halfWindow) {
    int n = data.length;
    float[] result = new float[n];
    float sum = 0.000000000f;
    for (int i=0; i<2*halfWindow; i++) {
        float d = data[i];
        sum += d * d;
    }
    result[halfWindow] = calcRms(halfWindow, sum);

    for (int i=halfWindow+1; i<n-halfWindow; i++) {
        float oldValue = data[i-halfWindow-1];
        float newValue = data[i+halfWindow-1];
        sum -= (oldValue*oldValue);
        sum += (newValue*newValue);
        float rms = calcRms(halfWindow, sum);
        result[i] = rms;
    }

    return result;
}

private static float calcRms(int halfWindow, float sum) {
    return (float) Math.sqrt(sum / (2*halfWindow));
}
```

For some background: 
I am trying to optimize a function that calculates a rolling root mean square (RMS) function on signal data.  The optimization is pretty important; it's a hot-spot in our processing.  The basic equation is simple - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square - Sum the squares of the data over the window, divide the sum by the size of the window, then take the square.

The original code:

```
public static float[] getRms(float[] data, int halfWindow) {
    int n = data.length;
    float[] result = new float[n];
    for (int i=halfWindow; i < n - halfWindow; i++) {
        float sum = 0;
        for (int j = -halfWindow; j < halfWindow; j++) {
            sum += (data[i + j] * data[i + j]);
        }
        result[i] = calcRms(halfWindow, sum);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code is slow because it reads the entire window from the array at each step, instead of taking advantage of the overlap in the windows.  The intended optimization was to use that overlap, by removing the oldest value and adding the newest.

I've checked the array indices in the new version pretty carefully. It seems to be working as intended, but I could certainly be wrong in that area!

**Update:**
With our data, it was enough to change the type of `sum` to a double.  Don't know why that didn't occur to me.  But I left the negative check in.  And FWIW, I was also able to implement a sol'n where recomputing the sum every 400 samples gave great run-time and enough accuracy.  Thanks.

Comment: try it with `double` instead of `float`. But a check on negative will even then be needed probably.

Comment: What is the range of your data, and what is the maximum value of halfWindow? Your `float` data has 24-bit significands. Their exact squares have 48 bits or fewer. If you scale the `float` to integer and convert to `long`, you have 15 bits to spare, so it might be possible to maintain the sum with exact arithmetic in a `long`, if the span of the range is not too great and halfWindow is not too large. This is likely feasible only if **all** your data is near the  1e-7 and 1e-8 you mention. Greater data will make the range too large. A “head and tail” approach with `double` might do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is this a floating-point error problem?

Yes it is. Due to rounding, you could well get negative values after subtracting a previous summand.

For example:

```
    float sum = 0f;
    sum += 1e10;
    sum += 1e-10;
    sum -= 1e10;
    sum -= 1e-10;
    System.out.println(sum);
```

On my machine, this prints

```
-1.0E-10
```

even though mathematically, the result is exactly zero.

This is the nature of floating point: `1e10f + 1e-10f` gives exactly the same value as `1e10f`.

As far as mitigation strategies go:

1. You could use `double` instead of `float` for enhanced precision.
2. From time to time, you could fully recompute the sum of squares to reduce the effect of rounding errors.
3. When the sum goes negative, you could either do a full recalculation as in (2) above, or simply set the sum to zero. The latter is safe since you know that you'll be pushing the sum towards its true value, and never away from it.

Comment: Any suggestions on solving it? I could really use the runtime gain from this, should I be able to get it to work.  I could see just rounding up to zero, should it go negative -- but I don't like that a bit.

Comment: @AbGator: Setting the sum to zero is less of a hack than it sounds. See (3) in my latest edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your indices in the second loop. The last value of `i` will be `n-halfWindow-1` and `n-halfWindow-1+halfWindow-1` is `n-2`.

You may need to change the loop to `for (int i=halfWindow+1; i<n-halfWindow+1; i++)`.

Comment: Although this isn't the real cause of the misbehavior ... I believe you're right!

Answer (score 0):

You are running into issues with floating point numbers because you believe that they are just like mathematical real numbers.  They are not, they are approximations of real numbers, mapped into discrete numbers, with a few special rules added into the mix.

Take the time to read up on [what every programmer should know about floating point numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), if you intend to use them often.  Without some care the differences between floating point numbers and real numbers can come back and bite you in the worst ways.

Or, just take my word for it and know that every floating point number is "pretty close" to the requested value, with some being "dead on" accurate, but most being "mostly" accurate.  This means you need to account for measurement error and keep it in mind after the calculations or risk believing you have an exact result at the end of the computation of the value (which you don't).